# New Site Popup Not Working

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer

When we try to create a new site or new document library in IE11, the popup window is blank or we get an app crash error.  It works fine in Chrome.  Any ideas?

We are using SharePoint 2010 with IE 11.  Compatibility and enterprise modes do not work either.

Comment: Any customization has been applied to the site? Custom master pages come to mind as a first guess.